# How to create initialized Spring bean (in session scope)

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I am trying to create multi-tab (JavaScript tabs) interface for Spring/facelets application and I have s.c. window manager that holds array of windows (tabs). Each window (tab) contains Spring bean (session scope) which receive (as injections) other spring beans, e.g. for business services, DAO beans and so on. I am using Primefaces p:tabView for facelets part.

When user creates new tab, the new Spring bean (as part of the window/tab) should be created and added to the window manager bean (WindowManager.addWindow(...) has method that is colled from the p:commandButton and that creates window/tab and its session been). The question is - how to create this bean and initialize it (with injected beans)? One solution maybe is to call ctx.getBean("beanName"), but I am afraid to use this because it has name and this name seems to be unique.

Maybe programmatical creation of Spring beans is not good design (they should be created automatically but the web server/Spring context when they process the web requests), but it seems to be necessary in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You must define that bean with scope "prototype", this setting causes that Spring context create a new fresh instance in every call to context.getBean("beanName");

To configure that, you can use:

```
@scope("prototype")
```

or

```
<bean id="beanName" class="com.foo.myBean" scope="prototype"/>
```

Depending on whether you are using java or xml configuration. Take a look to the Spring documentation for more details:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html